# Не переведено сообщение при попытке открыть удалённый вопрос

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, удаление-вопросов

[Нахождение максимального отрицательного корня уравнения без заданного интервала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931343/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11169

Добавил перевод:

> Этот вопрос был $commentSpan$удалён с сайта
>   $siteName$ в процессе модерации$spanClose$. Чтобы узнать возможные
>   причины удаления вопроса, обратитесь в справочный центр.

И похожая строка https://ru.traducir.win/string/11168

Добавил перевод:

> Ваш вопрос был $commentSpan$удалён с сайта $siteName$ в процессе
>   модерации$spanClose$. Чтобы узнать возможные причины удаления вашего
>   вопроса, обратитесь в справочный центр.